# preserve google maps settings screen until user takes action

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I press a button and a dialog appears where the user selects if he wants to navigate to saved position.

Inside dialog:

```
String query = "SELECT latitude,longitude FROM MEMS ";
Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);

    if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {

    do {                
        String mylatitude=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
        String mylongitude=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("longitude"));

        mylat=mylatitude;
        mylon=mylongitude;  

        } while (c1.moveToNext());
        }
            }

        c1.close();

        if(gps.canGetLocation ){

            current_latitude=gps.getLatitude();
                current_longitude=gps.getLongitude();

                }else{
                      }     

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + 
        current_latitude + "," + 
        current_longitude + "&daddr=" + mylat + "," + mylon ));

    startActivity(intent);
```

Now, when I press "OK" in order to start navigating , a dialog appears (from google maps) where it says that "some services are not available etc " and it has a button to go to settings in order to activate the services.

But the problem is that it doesn't wait for the user to press the settings button.It just shows up for 1 second and immediately starting to find position (but it can't because services are off).

What should i do for this?Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

I am uploading some screenshots:

The screen to enable GPS :

[image: enable GPS]

The screen which starts loading immediately after the previous screen:

[image: here]

Maybe this is some kind of phone's problem?

Comment: Have you set all the required permissions in the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_settings_in_the_application_manifest)?

Comment: @Aaron McIver:Yes,of course.But the app works fine.All ok with the map.The only problem is that when I don't have the GPS settings activated and go to map,the settings screen that appears stays only for a second.So,the user can't press "Settings".The code above seems ok , right?I mean, I load some values and then the Intent starts.Maybe we must add sthn inside the intent?Some command?I don't know.Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron McIver:I tried this.  "intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
    getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);" and the settings screen (first image above) staid until you press it!BUT , running the app again , I have still the same unfortunately..